# Can't access serial ports setting in virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I try to access the serial ports setting but I can't change the setting.

screenshot:
http://postimg.org/image/lx6gs8pgd/

Comment: Do you have permissions to /dev/ttyS0 on your host machine?

Comment: how do I get permission to /dev/ttyS0?

Comment: Try following command: ls -l /dev/ttyS0.

Comment: crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Aug 10 15:50 /dev/ttyS0 , I want to enable serial port, if there is another solution that will be excellent.

Comment: This means that you don't permission to serial port as regular user. Please add you user account to "dialout" group. This will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your useraccount to **dialout** group.
You can do it as root from command line:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout your_username
```

Comment: I did it but I still can't access the serial ports setting.

Comment: groups freescale
freescale : freescale adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxsf

Comment: Did you logout/login after changing group?

Comment: Just to check temporary run: chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0

Comment: Also please see following link for ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112568/how-do-i-allow-a-non-default-user-to-use-serial-device-ttyusb0

Comment: I try to connect to device, I use putty, how can I know what is the serial port? Maybe this is the problem.I still can't access the setting.

Comment: Try please "minicom -s". This will open serial communication proglem. From startup menu select "Serial port setup" and configure your serial port settings.

Comment: I ran `chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0` as `sudo` to get it to run. Does it mean I'm not getting a direct root all the way ?